# Functional Taylor series

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

The functional Taylor series of the functinal $f$ about the function $g$ is defined as

$f[g+\epsilon\lambda(x)]=f[g_0]+\int dx \frac{\delta f[g_0]}{\delta g(x)}\lambda(x)+\frac{1}{2!}\int dx dx^\prime \frac{\delta^2f[g_0]}{\delta g(x^\prime)\delta g(x)}\lambda(x)\lambda(x') + ... $

(it is assumed that $\lambda(x)=0$ outside the interval in question)

but in what sense does this converge? Usually this means that the derivatives of both sides are the same.

Following the text [here](http://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Classical%20Field%20Theory/Class%20Notes/Field%20Theory%20Chapter%205.pdf). How does the author derive

$D_{\lambda_1}D_{\lambda_2}(f(g))=\int dx dx^\prime \frac{\delta^2f[g_0]}{\delta g(x^\prime)\delta g(x)}\lambda(x)\lambda(x') $

I know how to compute derivatives by definition as described [here](http://www.physicspages.com/2014/11/08/functionals-and-functional-derivatives/), or by a way similar to the derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations. Where does the double integral come from in the equation above?

I have my own way (maybe it's wrong) to construct such integrals as limiting differentials

$$\Delta g=g+\epsilon\lambda-g=\epsilon\lambda$$
$$df=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_i}\Delta g=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial g(x_0+\epsilon i)}\epsilon\lambda(x_0+\epsilon i)$$
Taking the limit, treating each point as a separate variable, we get
$$df=\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial g(x)}\lambda(x) dx$$
Similarly for second order. But I fail to deduce, how this implies convergence of the Taylor series (first equation). How, or which derivatives match comparing left side with the right side of the equality? I would greatly appreciate any clarification.

Please forgive any lapses, I am an amateur exploring his interest.

Comment: The second link is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at taylor series of functions,

$$T_f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{d^i}{dx^i}f(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^i}{i!}$$
where the derivatives are explicitly evaluated at a point $x_0$, and are as such treated as constants, the derivative of $T_f$ with respect to $x$ is to be taken, and not $x_0$.

It is the same with functional analog of the taylor series, the term

$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta g(x)}$$
is to be treated as a constant, because the variation was evaluated at a particular function $g$. You are to take the derivative of your expression with respect to $\lambda(x)$, and not $g$, just as we took derivatives of $T_f(x)$ with respect to $x$ and not $x_0$.